# Hide any tabpanel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `tabsetPanel()` and I try to hide one `tabPanel()` if choice is two and `checkbox` is on. I tried the following code to do that, however it does not work.

**ui**

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(5,
               radioButtons("radio", label = h5("Data uploaded"),
                            choices = list("Aff" = 1, "Cod" = 2,
                                           "Ill" = 3),selected = 1)
        )),
      checkboxInput("checkbox", "cheb", value = F)
  ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", "plot1"),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.radio !=2 && input.checkbox == false",
        tabPanel("Summary", "summary1")
        ),
        tabPanel("Table", "table1")
      )
    )
  )

)
)
```

**server**

```
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

})
```

How can I hide a `tabPanel()`?

Comment: hide or show if this condition: `"input.radio ==2 && input.checkbox == true"` is met. The description doesnt match the code i think :)

Comment: You could do something like [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/Coe8drGPJbU/5JXdisgVFAAJ)

Comment: :) just wanted to add that as an alternative, as sthg closer to `conditionalPanel()` is seeked. Good idea.

Comment: @SBista Thank you. Can I do something like `condition = input$radio && inpu$checkbox`, I mean two condition seems not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add dynamic tabs in shiny dashboard using conditional panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931578/add-dynamic-tabs-in-shiny-dashboard-using-conditional-panel)

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with `renderUI()`:
Create the `tabpanels()` in a list within the `renderUI()`
and conditionally add the third one:
`if(input$radio == 2 & !input$checkbox)`
and then return the whole `tabsetPanel()` with `do.call(tabsetPanel, panels)`.

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(
          column(5,
                 radioButtons("radio", label = h5("Data uploaded"),
                              choices = list("Aff" = 1, "Cod" = 2,
                                             "Ill" = 3),selected = 1)
          )),
        checkboxInput("checkbox", "cheb", value = F)
      ),
      mainPanel(
          uiOutput("summary")
        )
      )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  output$summary <- renderUI({
      panels <- list(
        tabPanel("Plot", "plot1"),
        tabPanel("Table", "table1")        
      )
      if(input$radio == 2 & !input$checkbox) panels[[3]] <- tabPanel("Summary", "summary1")
      do.call(tabsetPanel, panels)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do with `conditionalPanel`

Comment: Well first of all, you are welcome. Concerning your question: I doubt it, because i afaik `conditionalPanel()` is a panel itself. If you read the docu `?conditionalPanel()`, the arguments are called `... =  
Elements to include in the panel.` So you would try to put a panel within a panel, while you just want to add a condition to a panel,...To my knowledge `renderUI()` would be the best practise here. What did your research show you, any hints it could work anyway?