# How to create a shiny App where tabs are only become visible if a condition is met

Tags: r, dynamic, tabs, conditional-statements, rshiny

I would like to create a ShinyApp with two tabs and in each tab there is a question that needs to be answered. The user should only see the secend tab with the second question if the user has answered the first question correctly beforehand.
Is there a possibility that the tab "Question2" will only be displayed if the user have previously answered the first question correctly in the tab "Question1"?
I created a minimal example, but i did not manage to hide tab two.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Header"),
    sidebarPanel(
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.tabselected ==1",
            sliderInput(
                inputId = "slider1",
                label = "Slider 1",
                min = 0,
                max = 1,
                value = 0.5
                ),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "quiz1",
                label = " Right or wrong",
                selected = NULL,
                choices = c("Right",
                            "Wrong")
            ),
            conditionalPanel(
                    "input.quiz1 === 'Right'",
                    paste0("Feedback: Right"),
                    actionButton("Tab2", label = "Next Question")
                    ),
          conditionalPanel(
                    "input.quiz1 === 'Wrong'",
                    paste0("Feedback: Wrong")
         ),
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.tabselected ==2",
            sliderInput(
                inputId = "slider2",
                label = "Slider 2",
                min = 0,
                max = 1,
                value = 0.5
                  ),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "quiz2",
                label = "True or false",
                selected = NULL,
                choices = c("false",
                            "true")
            ),
             conditionalPanel(
                    "input.quiz2 === 'true'",
                    paste0("Feedback: Right answer")         
            ),
           conditionalPanel(
                    "input.quiz2 === 'false'",
                    paste0("Feedback: Wrong answer")
) ) ),
    mainPanel(
             tabsetPanel(
            type = "tabs",
          tabPanel(
                "Question 1",
                titlePanel("Description question 1"),
                value = "1"
            ), 
    
          tabPanel(title = "Question  2" ,
                value = "2",
                conditionalPanel("input.quiz1 === 'Right'",
                    titlePanel("Description question 2")
                   ) 
            ), 
             id = "tabselected"
 ))))


server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$Tab2, {
       updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabselected",
                        selected = "2")
    })
 }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Do you have missing bracket (`(`) in ui code? Even after completing that I get ` argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default`. Can you confirm if the code works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find a solution to conditional tabsets in the link below, this is done on the server side with `renderUI()` and shown achieved with conditional panels

[Add dynamic tabs in shiny dashboard using conditional panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931578/add-dynamic-tabs-in-shiny-dashboard-using-conditional-panel)

A closer example of adding tabs to an existing tab set can be achieved with the code below (derived from examples in the original link):

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        checkboxGroupInput("Tabs", label = h4("tabpanel"), choices = list("tabs" = "tabs"),selected = NULL),
        checkboxGroupInput("MoreTabs", label = h4("moretabpanel"), choices = list("moretabs" = "moretabs"),selected = NULL)
    ),
    dashboardBody(
       tabBox(id="x",tabPanel("panel","panel"))
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) { 

    observeEvent(input$Tabs,{
       
        check1 <- input$Tabs == "tabs"
        
        if(check1&!is.na(check1)){
           
        
            insertTab(inputId = "x",
                      tabPanel("Dynamic", "This a dynamically-added tab"),target="panel",position ="after")
        }
        
    })
    }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

We use the function `insertTab` to append a tab to an existing tabset based on an event. (checking a box) if you want to subsequently remove this tab if the condition becomes unsatisfied again you can use `removeTab` more information on these functions can be found here:

[Shiny Insert Tab](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/insertTab.html)